# X8 mini, use phone storage for apps

Tags: applications, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, storage, internal-sd

I have an iOcean x8 mini. I am getting insufficient storage error when trying to install apps. So I went to my settings - data storage and see this.

[image]
[image]

So there are 2 storages in my phone. The apps are being installed into the Internal Storage. But I have plenty of space in the phone storage, is there any way I can install my apps to the phone storage instead of internal one?

Comment: By "Phone Storage" they probably mean an internal SD Card partition.  Unless the application (and your phone) support installing apps to SD, you'll be forced to install on your internal storage.  To check this, go to Settings>Applications and select a downloaded app, then see if you can move the storage location.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward It seems that my phone doesn't support that. Are there any hacks for this? Like root etc.?